# Can't install MySQL in python in windows

Tags: python, c++, mysql, django, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to make my first sample app with Django and 
I am trying to install mysql-python using `pip install mysql-python` and I am getting this error:

[image]

It's asking me to install Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 if I am not wrong. But, from what I have seen on the internet, to install Microsoft Visual C++ I have to install Microsoft Visual Studio(if I am not wrong).

So, My question is is there any other way to install Visual C++. Or is there any other way to install mysql for python.

Comment: So you want to install Visual C++ but you don't want to install Visual C++? Eh.

Comment: I don't want to install Visual Studio, I wan't to know if there is any other way around this problem??

Comment: which python version are you using ?

Comment: @MuhammadShoaib I am using Python 3.4

Comment: Try installing mysql connector before pip install mysql-python. I have shared the link
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/6.0.html#downloads

Comment: @MuhammadShoaib I just tried it out. But, unfortunately, the same error persists.

Comment: Try using 2.7 version of python

Comment: @MuhammadShoaib Yes, Python 2.7 did the work. But, it would have been nice to use 3.4

Answer (score 2):

You do not need Visual C++ to install `mysql-python`, but you *do* need a compiler to *build* `mysql-python`, which is what you are trying to do.

The helpful people who wrote the build script have seen fit to require a specific compiler; in this case, it's Visual C++ 10.0. And, yes, that is part of the Visual Studio product.

Find a pre-built version of `mysql-python` instead. You don't need to build your own copy.

Comment: I came across this site https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5#downloads to download mysql-python. But it doesn't support Python 3. Since I am new to Python, I don't know what is the difference between Python 2.7 and 3.X. Should I  go back to Python 2.7 for this?

Comment: @ParthapratimNeog: If you want to use MySQL-Python, and MySQL-Python only supports Python 2.7, then um I'd say yes you should use Python 2.7...

Comment: Can you tell me if there are any other ways to use mysql database using drivers other than mysql-python?

Comment: @ParthapratimNeog: I'm sure there are. Have a search.